# returning int functions that deal with arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am new to c++ and not yet grasp fully the concept of functions. This code I wrote is supposed to get an array and display the array, the highest number, and the lowest. Everything works except displaying the lowest and highest. I am confused about how to return these values and display them.

```
int find_highest(int array[], int size)
    {
        int count;
        int highest1;
        highest1 = array[0];
        for (count = 1; count < size; count++)
        {
            if (array[count] > highest1)
                highest1 = array[count];
        }
        cout << "The highest values is: " << highest1 << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: the input is ten values the output is those ten values.It should be those 10 values then the highest value then the lowest value

Comment: Please Enter Ten values
 Entry number 1:  23
Entry number 2:  3
...
 Entry number 10:  0
23 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 ----- this is where the code stops**
it should then display the highest number in the array and the lowest

Comment: It does that, but you need to put a pause at the end so that it doesn't close the window straight away. use cin.get(); as a basic "wait for keypress" command. Sometimes you need to flush the cin stream before cin.get however, using cin.ignore(); and/or cin.clear(); this is only if you used cin earlier, there could be some unmatched characters left in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

A function with a return value must pass that out via the return keyword. e.g. you've got findHighest:

```
int find_highest(int array[], int size)
{
    int count;
    int highest1;
    highest1 = array[0];
    for (count = 1; count < size; count++)
    {
        if (array[count] > highest1)
            highest1 = array[count];
    }

    // replace the cout with a return:  
    // cout << "The highest values is: " << highest1 << endl;
    return highest1; 
}
```

Note that the function always ends when a return is hit, so that if you have a function with separate branches each with a return statement, those signify where the function exits (it's better form however to have one return point at the bottom if possible, especially for large, complicated functions).

Now, you make a variable in the calling function to hold the returned value, and you can work with that in main now:

```
int highest = find_highest(array, ten_values);
cout << "The highest values is: " << highest << endl;
```

Alternatively you can just call the function directly now from inside a print command, if you don't need to use highest for anything else:

```
cout << "The highest value is: " << find_highest(array, ten_values) << endl;
```

Comment: AHH Thank you! This work you saved me from a headache... LOL